# Datagridview rows clear after a process

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working with a invoice billing application in c#, I wanted to reset my datagridview after saving and printing my invoice I need to make my form ready to make another invoice without restarting the form. I have tried all the known possible ways to make my datagridview's rowcount=1, couldn't make it with

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

also i tried with

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
```

all these methods are clearing my rows and cells but when I enter a new row after clearing datagridview it is entering into the row which is left from old (`dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1]`)so its leaving all other rows blank and entering new row how to solve this issue?

**EDITED**

I am adding rows like this

```
dataGridView1.RowCount = RowCount + 1;
string SQLStatement = "Select * from Stock_ManagerDB where STKItemCode='" + dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[1].Value + "'";
SqlDataReader myreader = DBConnection.viewDetails(SQLStatement);
if (myreader.Read())
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[2].Value = myreader["STKItemName"].ToString().Trim();
    dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[3].Value = 1;
    dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[4].Value = (string)myreader["STKCategory"].ToString().Trim();
    dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[5].Value = (string)myreader["SellingPrice"].ToString().Trim();
    dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[6].Value = labelDiscOperator.Text;
    label_avlQty.Text = (string)myreader["STKQTY"].ToString().Trim();
    dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[15].Value = (string)myreader["STKQTY"].ToString().Trim();
    btnloadDGDGT();
    btnstockupdate();
}
```

Comment: Are you using a DataSource?  If not, clearly `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();` should work.

Comment: no it i not a data bonded, just a user entering controls,  it's not working for me that y I wonder.

Comment: What is the value of your **RowCount** at **dataGridView1.RowCount = RowCount + 1;**? did you reset the value, perhaps it store your previous value? and why don't you use dataGridView1.RowCount instead of RowCount since you add and minus it again?

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Rows.Clear();  //if datasource is datatable
```

else

```
((DataSet)dataGridView1.DataSource).Tables[0].Rows.Clear(); //if datasource is dataset
```